# Maintaining the order of a vector when applying it to setNames of a list

Tags: r

The following dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(9*9), ncol=9))
names(df) <- c("c_1", "d_1", "e_1", "a_p", "b_p", "c_p", "1_o1", "2_o1", "3_o1")
row.names(df) <- names(df)
```

...is split by rownames according to common indices found after "_" and i release dataframes from the list to the global environment:

```
list_all <- split(df,sub(".+_","",rownames(df)))
list2env(list_all,envir=.GlobalEnv)
```

Many of my dataframes have now numeric names, and cannot be adressed easily, so i want to change their names. Id like to add "df_" to every name, but since i dont know how to do it, i was told make.names could be nice. I create a vector of all unique indices, and factorize it, which i think maintains the original order of the indices:

```
indx <- gsub(".*_", "", names(df))
indx1 <- factor(indx, levels=unique(indx))
new.names <- make.names(unique(indx1))
new.names
[1] "X1" "p"  "o1"
```

new.names is in the order i want it to be. I apply the new names to the list, and release it to the environment
    list_all <- setNames(list_all, new.names) 
    list2env(list_all,envir=.GlobalEnv)

Now, the numeric names have an added leading X (nice!), but the sequence of the dataframes has changed and names have been wrongly assigned (dataframe p contains now all rows with "o1" and vice versa).

- Questions:

  1. Is there an easy way to add strings to object names of the same class in a workspace?
  2. If i am going to do it with the make.names route, how can i absolutely make sure that the vectors in list_all are named in the
     same order as in new.names?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not simply using, just after having created `list_all`:

```
names(list_all) = paste0("df_", names(list_all))
list2env(list_all,envir=.GlobalEnv)
#> df_1
#            c_1        d_1        e_1        a_p        b_p        c_p       1_o1         2_o1        3_o1
#c_1  1.10388982 -0.2329471 -0.3330288 -2.0477186 -1.4576052  1.5411154 -0.9529714  0.289516457 -0.01017546
#d_1 -1.02420662 -0.1002591 -0.7884373  1.5021531  0.3551084  0.7755127  0.7679464 -0.002950944 -0.69849456
#e_1 -0.02004774 -0.1873947 -0.3674220  0.7321503  0.9076226 -0.4997974 -0.2915408 -1.376529597 -1.43563284
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function that I think does what you want:

```
# dummy data:
x <- numeric(0)
y <- numeric(0)
z <- numeric(0)

df1 <- data.frame()
df2 <- data.frame()
df3 <- data.frame()
df4 <- data.frame()

renameObjects <- function(env=.GlobalEnv, class, pfx) {  
  objs <- ls(envir = env) # get list of objects

  classes <- sapply(objs, function(x) class(get(x))) == class

  for (obj in objs[classes]) {
    assign(paste0(pfx, obj), get(obj), envir = env)
  }
  rm(list=objs[classes], envir = env)  
}

# run the function
renameObjects(class='data.frame', pfx = 'my_prefix_')
```

Results

```
> ls()
[1] "df1"           "df2"           "df3"           "df4"          
[5] "renameObjects" "x"             "y"             "z"            
> renameObjects(class='data.frame', pfx = 'my_prefix_')
> ls()
[1] "my_prefix_df1" "my_prefix_df2" "my_prefix_df3" "my_prefix_df4"
[5] "renameObjects" "x"             "y"             "z"
```

Comment: The OP does not necessarily want to modify names of ALL `data.frame` in the `Global envrionment` but just the ones in `list_all`.